# Regex: Java->C++11

Tags: java, regex, c++11

I'm trying to port this java line:

```
Pattern P = Pattern.compile("[\uD800\uDC00-\uDB7F\uDFFF]");
```

into c++11:

```
typedef std::regex<std::wstring> Pattern;
Pattern P("[\uD800\uDC00-\uDB7F\uDFFF]");
```

but I get:

```
error: invalid universal character "[\uD800\uDC00-\uDB7F\uDFFF]"
```

The java source i'm porting is https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/jsonldjava/core/Regex.java

I'm not an expert with encoding and regexp tricks and standards. Your help will be very appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you need to escape the slashes, then the error disappears: `Pattern P("[\\uD800\\uDC00-\\uDB7F\\uDFFF]");`

Comment: I guess `std::regex` does not support `\uFFFF` to match Unicode code points.